# Postman how to use Get Requests by read URLs from various .txt files

Tags: url, import, postman, get-request

I hopefully have a simple request but unable to do by myself due Postman's
file support behaviour.
Case:
Lots of people creating simple URLs for a maschine learning tool and pushing them into a database.
The URLs got just simple differencies of an count up ID Number to request the appropriate information.
However, at the end of the day we got lots of simple single textfiles each
with 1 single url line.
What I just wanna do is to push the whole folder into Postman to finally test all created URLs and save the rsult as json...hm
Postman does not support textfiles and yeah thats crackbrained but I dunno how?

Any idea is welcome?

Thanks a lot in advance
brgds

Answer (score 0):

1. You can export a Postman's Collection and see how the requests in it are exported (The JSON Format of a request is to be noted).
2. Now you know the format of a request, you can create a script that'll just run through all your files and basically generate a request out of each URL and add that to the exported collection's JSON.
3. Finally, import the collection back into Postman and you'll have all the requests ready to be tested out.

Comment: Hi,
that sounds good thanks for your reply.
We'll try this and come back with the result.

Comment: @YoullNeverSee Sure thing. No problem =)